# Where does "insert overwrite local directory" create file on local file system?

Tags: hive

The INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY command in Hive creates a file on the local filesystem, but which node's local filesystem will the file be created on? Will it always be the namenode or any node that happens to run the job?

Answer (score 0):

> which node's local filesystem will the file be created on?

The file will be created on the system where you execute the hive query.

**Example:** If you have `two nodes`, `one namenode` and `one slave` node. And if you run the hive query on slave node, the file will be created on the slave node's filesystem.

> **NOTE:** If you want to have two hive installations on both namenode and slave node, just use this property: **hive.metastore.uris** to point to both namenode and slave node locations.

The property should be like this:

```
<property>
    <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
    <value>thrift://namenode-ip:9083,thrift://slave-ip:9083</value>
</property>
```

Just change `namenode-ip` and `slave-ip` to respective IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

The file will be created locally on the node from which you execute the job.